# Failed to encrypt Chinese characters

Tags: c, openssl

I use `RSA_public_encrypt()` to encrypt a string in Chinese. For example:

```
char buf[] = "你好";
RSA_public_encrypt(s, buf, p, r, RSA_NO_PADDING);
```

The error string returned by OpenSSL is:

```
error:04068084:lib(4):func(104):reason(132)
```

It will fail. I want to know why?

Comment: According to [`RSA_public_encrypt`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html) man page: *"On error, -1 is returned; the error codes can be obtained by `ERR_get_error`..."* The next question is, what is the error code returned by the library?

Comment: error:04068084:lib(4):func(104):reason(132)。it's error message

Answer (score 2):

> `error:04068084:lib(4):func(104):reason(132)`

That's fairly useless. When you see a string like that, use the `openssl errstr` command:

```
$ openssl errstr 0x04068084
error:04068084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_ENCRYPT:data too large for modulus
```

It looks like your example does not match the actual code that's producing the error. Or the OpenSSL error message is wrong - it should say *"data too small for modulus"*.

The string you are encrypting has a size limit. From [`RSA_public_encrypt`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html):

> RSA_public_encrypt() encrypts the flen bytes at from (usually a session key) using the public key rsa and stores the ciphertext in to. to must point to RSA_size(rsa) bytes of memory...
>
> flen must be less than RSA_size(rsa) - 11 for the PKCS #1 v1.5 based padding modes, less than RSA_size(rsa) - 41 for RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING and exactly RSA_size(rsa) for RSA_NO_PADDING. The random number generator must be seeded prior to calling RSA_public_encrypt().

According to the man page, since you are using `RSA_NO_PADDING`, the string being encrypted must be exactly `RSA_size(rsa)` in length. Effectively, that means you are responsible for padding instead of the library.

Above, a ***session key*** is usually small, like 16 or 32 bytes. Usually what happens is the *session key* is used to key a block or stream cipher like AES, Camellia, TripleDES, ChaCha, etc. Then, the plaintext is encrypted under the block or stream cipher. Finally, the block or stream cipher key is encrypted under the RSA key.

You might also be interested in *[Key Encryption Key (KEK)](http://www.google.com/search?q=Key+Encryption+Key)* and *[Content Encryption Key (CEK)](http://www.google.com/search?q=Content+Encryption+Key)*. They are part of a *key management* strategy. Above, the RSA key is your *Key Encryption Key (KEK)*, and the *Content Encryption Key (CEK)* is the session key.

Comment: key is 1024bits，when i encrypt a english string(128bytes)，i succed。“你好” only 6bytes

Comment: @mc.robin = perform a `strlen` on the Chinese character string and see what it returns. I'm guessing its greater than the limits. Maybe you need to set a C locale for your program. Maybe you need to convert to UTF8 string using `iconv`. Sorry I don't know more about i18n.

Comment: @mc.robin "when i encrypt a english string(128bytes)，i succed" - that's precisely the point. Did you read the link provided in this answer? From the documentation, "flen must be ... exactly RSA_size(rsa) for RSA_NO_PADDING". If the sequence you're passing is not *exactly* the modulus size (in this case 128 bytes for a 1024-bit key) the encryption *will fail*.

Comment: @jww You have it here. its ok. If you desire, just update your answer (which I already upticked anyway) and highlight the portion specified. The trouble of doing this (making a modulus sized frame) is one of several reasons I *don't* use no-padding. Almost everyone uses v1.5 or oaep anyway. Not sure why the OP isn't.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Use RSA_PKCS1_PADDING will work. I don't know why...

Comment: @mc.robin - You might consider `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` instead of `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`. The man page tells you to use `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` for new applications: *"This mode is recommended for all new applications...."*. Also see Matthew Green's blog [A bad couple of years for the cryptographic token industry](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/06/bad-couple-of-years-for-cryptographic.html).